# Using JNI to call a method from C in java

Tags: c, eclipse, java-native-interface

I've thrown myself in the deep end here and used JNI and eclipse for the first time, while practicing my beginner level C skills.

I have the following code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNJEXPORT void JNICALL Java_AI_makeMove
(JNIEnv *env, jobject)
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

which generates these three errors:

```
expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
make: *** [src/MakeMove.o] Error 1  
recipe for target 'src/MakeMove.o' failed
```

I have added C:\Program Files (x86)java\jdk1.8.0_65\include and  C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_65\include\win32 to Project-->Properties-->C/C++ General-->Paths and Symbols

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

If I add the jni.h and jni-md.h files located under program files x86 to the include folder in MinGW, then instead of "expected identifier..." I get

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
```

**UPDATE2**

Changing JNJExport to JNIExport did indeed fix the first error, "expected identifier..." However the other two errors are still there. I am certain they are to do with the eclipse configuration since they also appear even if I try and build an empty script.

Comment: Did you get any other messages and/or errors?

Comment: @AndrewHenle None other than those 3 errors. Though before I added the two include paths I had another error which talked about not being able to find <jni.h> or something along those lines.

Comment: The errors you've posted are like what you would get if your compiler couldn't find `<jni.h>`.  `<jni.h>` should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)java\jdk1.8.0_65\include and C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_65\include`.  You may need both `C:\Program Files (x86)java\jdk1.8.0_65\include and C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_65\include` and `C:\Program Files (x86)java\jdk1.8.0_65\include and C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_65\include\win32` in your include paths.

Comment: @AndrewHenle as I posted originally, I have already added them to paths and symbols, putting them under both the "assembly" and "GNU C" languages sections of the includes in Paths and Symbols. The error for not being able to find <jni.h>, as I wrote in the comment above, only occured before I included them. Do I need to add these two include paths to somewhere else too? Cheers.

Comment: If you've added both the include paths - with and without the final `win32` directory, *and* you're not getting any "can't find include file" errors, I'd think offhand that you shouldn't be getting any errors.  Can you check the contents of `jni.h` and `win32\jni_md.h`?  (`jni.h` has a `#include "jni_md.h"` line it it - which is why you need *both* include paths.)  Did you generate a header file using `javah` from your Java class?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I did generate a header file, although I copied the contents of it into the eclipse script, which is in an entirely different folder. Should the .h file be in the eclipse workspace folder or somewhere like that too?

Comment: It's a simple typo. JNJEXPORT should be JNIEXPORT